# Add query results in columns SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, crosstab

I have this (result of my query):

```
    id |  suk | xpto
   ----+------+------
     4 | 1023 | abc
     4 | 1025 | def
     4 | 1200 | zzz
     4 | 1501 | ppp
     5 | 1111 | ola
     5 | 2222 | xau
```

I need transform in

```
    id |   suk    |    suk2  |   suk3   | suk4 
  -----+----------+----------+----------+-----------
     4 | 1023 abc | 1025 def | 1200 zzz | 1501 ppp
     5 | 1111 ola | 2222 xau |          |
```

Actually, my query is:

```
SELECT b.ID, s.SKU, s.EVENT_TYPE 
FROM VFIE_BONUS_POINTS_RULE b 
INNER JOIN VFIE_BONUS_POINTS_RULE_SKU s  
ON b.ID = s.ID_BNS_PTS_RL;
```

I use Oracle.

Is it possible?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you add the query that you currently have?

Comment: SELECT b.ID, s.SKU, s.EVENT_TYPE  
FROM VFIE_BONUS_POINTS_RULE b  
INNER JOIN VFIE_BONUS_POINTS_RULE_SKU s  
ON b.ID = s.ID_BNS_PTS_RL;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pivot` and `row_number()`. Instead of `t` put your query:

```
select * 
  from (select row_number() over (partition by id order by suk) rn, t.* from t)
  pivot (max(suk||' '||xpto) suk for rn in (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

---

Test:

```
with t(id, suk, xpto) as (select 4, 1023, 'abc' from dual
                union all select 4, 1025, 'def' from dual
                union all select 4, 1200, 'zzz' from dual
                union all select 4, 1501, 'ppp' from dual
                union all select 5, 1111, 'ola' from dual
                union all select 5, 2222, 'xau' from dual )
select * 
  from (select row_number() over (partition by id order by suk) rn, t.* from t)
  pivot (max(suk||' '||xpto) suk for rn in (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Output:

```
ID  1_SUK     2_SUK     3_SUK     4_SUK
--  --------  --------  --------  --------
 4  1023 abc  1025 def  1200 zzz  1501 ppp
 5  1111 ola  2222 xau
```

---

**Edit:**

> How can I change column name of the sku and xpto? Expected: SUK 1 -
>   XPTO 1

```
select id,"1_S" as "SUK 1", "1_X" as "XPTO 1", 
          "2_S" as "SUK 2", "2_X" as "XPTO 2", 
          "3_S" as "SUK 3", "3_X" as "XPTO 3", 
          "4_S" as "SUK 4", "4_X" as "XPTO 4"
  from (select row_number() over (partition by id order by suk) rn, t.* from t)
  pivot (max(suk) s, max(xpto) x for rn in (1, 2, 3, 4) )
```

More information about `pivot` in Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE).

Comment: Thank you. 
I could adapt to my case.

Comment: How can I separate sku and xpto?

Comment: Change pivot clause to: `pivot (max(suk) suk, max(xpto) xpto for rn in (1, 2, 3, 4))`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you again

Comment: How can I change column name of the sku and xpto?
Expected: SUK 1 - XPTO 1

Comment: Please see updated part of my answer. If you have additional questions I advise to ask new one on main site. I might be absent, not able to answer and other users may have better ideas ;-) As for now your question is fully answered. Thanks :-)